# Cannot create a file using the Uri of `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`

Tags: android, pdf, uri

I'm trying to select pdf file from the device and upload them to the server. `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` is used to select pdf from the device.

```
sel_book.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("application/pdf");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select PDF"), 1);
        }
    });
```

On activity result I get the Uri and save it as a String.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent result) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            Uri uri = result.getData();
            String uriString = uri.toString();
            File myFile = new File(uriString);
            path = myFile.getAbsolutePath();
        }
    }
}
```

It results the path as, `/document/primary:Download/Aptitude_2016_17.pdf`. I need to use this to create a new file. `File selectedFile = new File(selectedFilePath);`. But it doesn't create File. `selectedFile.isFile()` returns false. I have no idea why is it. Please help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ACTION_GET_CONTENT is used to select pdf from the device.

This allows the user to select a piece of content. It does not have to be a file.

> On activity result I get the Uri and save it as a String.

That is not how you use a `Uri`.

> It results the path as, /document/primary:Download/Aptitude_2016_17.pdf.

That is not a filesystem path. That is a part of a `Uri` that has a `content` scheme. You do not get a file from `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`. You get a `Uri` that points to a piece of content. That `Uri` could point to *anything that the user and the other app choose*:

- A file that you can access, via a `Uri` with a `file` scheme
- A file, but one that you cannot access (e.g., on internal storage of another app)
- The contents of a BLOB column in the database
- A piece of content that needs to be downloaded
- And so on

Use `ContentResovler` and `openInputStream()` to get a stream on whatever the content is. Either use that directly (with whatever you are using to upload this content), or use that stream to make your own file with a copy of that content, so that you have a file that you can use.

Comment: Thanks. Can you help me to get the filesystem path of the selected please.

Comment: @Choxmi: **There is no filesystem path**. The only way there will be one is if you create your own file, using `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()`, coupled with a `FileOutputStream` to some file that you control. Then, use standard Java I/O to copy from the input stream to the output stream. Then, you have your own file, with the content, that you can use for whatever purpose that you want. Feel free to delete the file when you are done with it.

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much for your reply.